# curs.fetchall() python in a nested list

Tags: python, list, insert, nested

```
curs.execute("Select ISBN,Rate From High_Scores")
rows2 = curs.fetchall()

for row in rows2:
    Book=row["ISBN"]
    Rate=row["Rate"]
```

I want to create a Nested List (Only this) with this structure "(Books,Rate) (Books,Rate) (Books,Rate) etc", how i can do this?

Comment: Have you tried using python `zip()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tupleOfRecords = [(row['ISBN'], row["Rate"]) for row in rows2]
```